# Google Rich Snippets not showing anymore

Tags: google-search, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets

I have been working on my site, and rich snippets.
Initially when I wrote the mark-up I checked on

> https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

and it evaluated the mark-up to be correct and after that I used Google Crawl tool. 
After those actions were performed the rich snippets appeared to work correctly on google, and every time I googled the site it used to display the correct rich snippets.

However, recently google has stopped displaying the rich snippets for my site, does anyone know what could be the reason?
Following is the mark-up I am using, and again evaluating it on https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets shows that there is no problem.

```
<div itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
    <meta itemprop="itemReviewed" content="Table Hire">
    <meta itemprop="author" content="Markus Sean">
    <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2012-05-10">
    <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
      <meta itemprop="worstRating" content = "1">
      <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content = "5">
      <meta itemprop="bestRating" content = "5">
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Google has set a newer, better tool: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/structured-data/testing-tool/ to test rich snippets. I have checked it withthis one and it is correct. On which URL do you serve the snippet?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using only meta tags.

Google says:

> Google will ignore content that isn't visible to human users, so you should mark up the text that visitors will see on your web pages.

[Rich snippets not appearing](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1093493?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Google only accepts snippets from inner pages. If you have added snippets on website homepage it will be not shown in search results. Have a look at google search results, you will find out that they show snippets with innerpages links.